# Preventing mouse clicks in inactive windows from repositioning the cursor

Tags: window, mouse, navigation

When I have Emacs (24.4, Mac OS, NS build) in the foreground, I often have many windows open in one frame. I sometimes want to switch windows by clicking in an inactive window. By default, this calls `mouse-set-point` which (1) activates the window I clicked in, and (2) repositions the point to wherever I clicked. I want to change this behavior so clicking in an inactive window would only activate it, but not move the cursor. If I'm in an active window, I want it to reposition the cursor to wherever I clicked.

Is there any reasonable way built into Emacs to do this?

**Edit 1:** I just tried this:

```el
(defadvice mouse-set-point (around cv/mouse-set-point (event) activate)
  (let ((event-target-window (caadr event)))
    (if (eql event-target-window (frame-selected-window))
        ad-do-it
      (set-frame-selected-window nil event-target-window))))
```

That doesn't work because `mouse-set-point` seems to fire in the new window to position itself.

**Edit 2:** Updated attempt:

```el
(defadvice mouse-set-point (around cv/mouse-set-point (event) activate)
  (let ((event-name (car event))
        (event-target-window (caadr event)))
    (if (and (eql 'down-mouse-1 event-name)
             (eql event-target-window (frame-selected-window)))
        ad-do-it
      (set-frame-selected-window nil event-target-window))))
```

This does not work in a weird way. When I click above the cursor position in the inactive window, it does what I want. When I click below the cursor position the inactive window, it moves the cursor. Two events fire consistently: `down-mouse-1` and then `mouse-1`. Both call `mouse-set-point`.

**Edit 3:** Replacing `mouse-set-point` does work, provided I also unset `[down-mouse-1]` (normally bound to `mouse-drag-region`):

```el
(defun mouse-set-point-2 (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (mouse-minibuffer-check event)
  (let ((event-target-window (caadr event)))
    (if (eql event-target-window (frame-selected-window))
        (posn-set-point (event-end event))
      (set-frame-selected-window nil event-target-window))))

(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'mouse-set-point-2)

(global-unset-key [down-mouse-1])
```

Not good enough, I don't want to lose drag-selection with the mouse.

**Edit 4:** Adding advice to both `mouse-set-point` and `mouse-drag-region` seems to work.

Comment: I would suggest something that does both -- if current window, then set point -- if not current window, then select window only.

Comment: I posted an answer saying that binding `[mouse-1]` to `mouse-select-window` ought to do the trick, but when I try it, that doesn't work. Perhaps because event `<down-mouse-1>` invokes `mouse-drag-region` first? Besides @lawlist makes a good point.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen -- the variable `flyspell-mouse-map` in `flyspell` has an example where `mouse-2` is `nil` and `down-mouse-2` is `flyspell-correct-word` -- perhaps a similar setup could be used.  However, I imagine the final solution will be an `advice` *before* `mouse-set-point` that checks the current window and uses the function you suggested if its not the current window -- else, the default setting.

Comment: The underlying function is only about 4 lines of code -- why not just make a new function that tests for whether the current window is the proposed selected window and then either select window (if not current window) or set point (if current window)?

Comment: That works, as long as I unbind `mouse-drag-region` from `[down-mouse-1]`, since that seems to do its own window switching. Unfortunately, that kills mouse drag-selection.

Comment: I think I got it now. Updating question and posting answer.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out a way to prevent a mouse click from moving the cursor _when the mouse click was to give focus to the frame_.  Under Windows, a mouse click is required to raise a window (frame) or give it focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following advice achieves the behavior I want:

```el
(defadvice mouse-set-point (around cv/mouse-set-point (event) activate)
  (let ((event-name (car event))
        (event-target-window (posn-window (event-start event))))
    (if (and (eql 'down-mouse-1 event-name)
             (eql event-target-window (selected-window)))
        ad-do-it
      (select-window event-target-window))))

(defadvice mouse-drag-region (around cv/mouse-drag-region (event) activate)
  (let ((event-target-window (posn-window (event-start event))))
    (if (eql event-target-window (selected-window))
        ad-do-it
      (select-window event-target-window))))
```

Comment: Why use advice (dangerous) when you can define your own command and bind it?

Comment: Faaaaantastic! :D

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution, but was getting "Symbol's function is void" from the caadr on Emacs 24.5. Fixed by adding (require 'cl) just before the defadvice stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that works well for me:

```
(defadvice mouse-set-point (after wlh/mouse-set-point-advice (event &optional promote-to-region) activate)
  "Advice mouse click to remove multi cursors when present."
  (when (> (mc/num-cursors) 1)
    (mc/remove-fake-cursors)))
```